# Как удалить файлы из потока вывода команды?

Tags: windows, cmd, потоки-данных

У меня есть такой вывод в консоль (выводятся названия файлов, которые надо удалить). Как передать это к команду `rm` ?

> ```
> dir /o:-d /b | gawk "FNR > 1 {print $0}"
> ```

при попытки сделать так:

> ```
> dir /o:-d /b | gawk "FNR > 1 {print $0}" | rm
> ```

получаю ошибку

> "rm: missing operand Try `rm --help' for more information."

Comment: перенаправляйте поток в утилиту поиска, которую будете парсить командой for. То есть в Вашем примере команду rm надо заменить на следующую: for /f %i in ('find /v /i""') do if not "%i" == "" rm %i

Comment: Как сделаете рабочий вариант, выложите его в форме ответа. И если это будет батч-файл, то скорее всего надо будет использовать двойной процент: вместо %i - %%i